# Is there a way to parse Golang printed maps in Python?

Tags: python, go, parsing

I mean something like

```py
go_map = 'map[customer_ids:[Test1 Test2]]'

parse(go_map)  # = {'customer_ids': ['Test1', 'Test2']}
```

Comment: Have you considered serializing to a common format like JSON?

Comment: I can't. This is the output of API Gateway's authorizer, and I can't do anything here. And I'm aware of a question that's related to the problem, but want to hope, there is a way without parsing the token again.

Comment: Go's `fmt` output isn't a serialization format, so there is no way to do this in general. If you have a known limited set of values, then you can parse it yourself pretty easily.

Comment: What is "API Gateway"? Sounds like it's broken (or not meant for programmatic consumption) if it's outputting Go-specific string formats rather than a standard serialization format.

Comment: single quotes accounts for invalid json, maybe you can Marshal the output into a struct in Go first to get the valid json before doing any further processing in python.